# How ro compensate for display magnification settings when doing image cropping

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I have a set of five year old applications that offer image cropping as a feature.  I now find that if the user has configured their displays at other that 100% magnification, my cropping rectangle software fails.  How do I compensate for the user's display settings to enlarge the display setting to more that 100% magnification?

*EDIT*
Some users have posted that this question has been answered, and it may well have been.  There are some interesting ideas in the quoted posts that may well apply to my problem. I want to clarify.  In Windows 10 it appears that it is a great deal easier to set the resolution of your monitor (or the size of your displayed items) that it was in Windows 7, which I currently use in development.  I now see that in a buried menu, I can set the size of displayed items from 100% to 125% and 150% in a system-wide display setting menu.  In Windows 10 there is a slider that also appears to have the same functionality that Windows 7 had in the buried menu.

My long standing code allows the user to make a cropping box inside a control that holds an image and to crop that image.  That code draws a cropping box around the area to be cropped.  When the user's display setting is set to 100%, the cropping box appears in the correct place on the image.  When the user's display setting is set to other than 100%, the cropping rectangle is not drawn in the correct place (i.e. in relation to the dragged mouse cursor used to define the cropping box).

Some responses say that I should set set the resolution of the image before I display it to the resolution of the graphics object being drawn into.  I assume that this would be affected by the user's global setting of the display size. Other users have said that I should temporarily set the user's resolution to 100% before allowing them to do the cropping.  This second idea is a non starter in my opinion.  I don't want to be messing with the user's predefined settings.

So I am going to do a little test to see if I can correct the problem by displaying the image the user crops at the resolution of the graphics object being drawn into.

But all this aside, this is only the start of the problems related to solving this issue.  The imaged displayed for the user to crop is a scaled down version of their original image. The application not only does cropping but also rotation, color correction, sharpening, etc.  For this reason, the application displays a low resolution image for the user to correct and to select a sharpening level. These preview operations are done in real time in a foreground thread, and then the correction job parameters and the original image filespec are passed to a background thread that handles the correction on the high-res original image, whilst the foreground thread starts on an new image.  So this information about what resolution is needed needs to be passed the background processing thread so that the cropped, rotated and corrected image are created essentially the same as the preview image, except for size and resolution.

This is all doable, of course, but it needs to be done correctly when the user's global screen resolution is other than 100%, and which could possibly be changed from image to image.  So I need to keep the resolution parameters used in the foreground to be passed to the background thread so it all works out.

Comment: *"my cropping rectangle software fails"* - badly? Or how? Can we have a look at sources or you just need a quick working solution? Then here is one: set user DPI (that's what you call magnification, right?) to 100%, do cropping and then return it back!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?